# Python Subprocess.call gives error with print passed through

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting an unexpected error with subprocess.call() and trying to execute a print statement.

Here's a simple version of my code that will reproduce the same error.

```
import subprocess
cmd = "print(1)"

subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error.

```
>>> subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
2
```

I've also tried to set the shell environment and get a different error.

```
>>> subprocess.call("print('1')",executable='/bin/bash', shell=True)
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `'1''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `print('1')'
```

What am I doing wrong when I pass the string command to be executed by the subprocess call?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS via WSL2 Windows 10.
this is part of a more complex call inside a docker container, but this simple example is the gist of my issue.

Comment: Both errors are essentially the same. It isn't valid syntax for a _shell command_

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want to run a print statement, just put it directly in the code. If you want to run an arbitrary string of python code, use `exec()`

Comment: okay. Thank you for pointing out the obvious -- It's a shell command. 

I was trying to echo a string to the shell from within a python script inside a docker container. 

But .. since it's outputted to the shell, i need to use a shell command, not a python function.  I was thinking in a python context, when I should have been thinking in the shell context. 

Thanks!!